# how to rewrite url with post data by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

The original url is result of post =>
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?s=&where=townsearch&search_simple=find

I wish to have this url =>
http://www.mywebsite.com/town/townsearch.html

That's possible with htaccess ?

I wish to keep the two url functionnal but rewrite the first to the second automatically if possible.
So when we enter the first url, it rewrite it on the browser to the second, or it redirect it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to you htaccess file and it will work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)s=($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)where=townsearch($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)search_simple=find($|&)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /town/townsearch.html?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, and it don't work, nothing happens, no redirection, no rewrite :(

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^town([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?s=$1&where=$2&search_simple=find [L]
```

It will leave you with the URL: `http://www.mywebsite.com/town/townsearch.html`

Comment: perhaps I missed something, but that's don't work
I already have RewriteEngine On at the top of my htaccess, so I just added the second line
A detail important, my full url is "http://www.mywebsite.com/?s=&where=mytown&search_simple=trouver" without the index.php, but work with too, so I tested with, or without